# Angular date min not being enforced

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some input type=date fields I am trying to enforce a minimum of today's date on via Angular.

According to the Angular docs, min= and max= should both be working, but they aren't.  My form never gets flagged as invalid, even when the date field is invalid.

I am testing on Chrome Beta, but this is being written in a Cordova/PhoneGap app to run on iOS 7.  it's not working either place.

My field looks like this:

```
<input name="dateDue" ng-class="{ invalid: form.myForm.dateDue.$invalid }" type="date" ng-model="todo.promiseDate" min="{{ minDate }}" required/>
```

minDate is being set in the controller as:

```
$scope.minDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');  // I have tried both with and without the filter.
```

So yeah - what am I missing?

TIA.

Comment: Have you tried min="minDate"?

Comment: @camden_kid That does not work.

Comment: Cordova does not handle min/max date/time. Here is a Cordova iOS workaround. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943511/limit-the-selectable-dates-in-native-datepicker-in-ios-phonegap-app/26086166#26086166

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here...

```
ng-class="{ invalid: form.myForm.dateDue.$invalid }"
```

The expression should be `<formname>.<fieldname>.$invalid`. Currently `form.myForm.dateDue.$invalid` evaluates to `undefined` which is always falsy. Try...

```
ng-class="{ invalid: myForm.dateDue.$invalid }"
```

Comment: The form is referenced correctly.  It's coming back in the controller as form.myForm, and I can see all the fields and such inside.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?